# How can I fix the Flutter error message: Color is not a type?

Tags: flutter, dart

Recently after running a Flutter Upgrade I noticed quite a few errors appeared regarding the Color type. For example the code below, Color is flagged as being an error. The error message is: Color is not a type.

```
class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String cardText;
  final String cardImage;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Category category;
  final VoidCallback choiceCardCallback;
```

After trying to find out why this had happened I did try compiling my app and have found that the app actually works fine, so there is no actual error. However having all these red errors flagged in the app, makes it difficult to see if there is a "real" error in there.

Comment: Have you tried removing the imported packages in the class, adding the packages again, and rebuilding the project? See if the rebuild clears out the errors.

Comment: If you are using android studio try file->invalidate caches and restart

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not even close to a permanent fix, though I would suggest that you let Flutter itself get the type of the variable...

I know that there are a lot of upsides to stating the type of variable during its initialization, though, as a temporary workaround, I would suggest that you declare a final variable like so for now:

```
class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final cardText;
  final cardImage;
  final width;
  final height;
  final color;
  final category;
  final choiceCardCallback;
```

Make sure that you include the final fields if needed in the class constructor:

```
ChoiceCard({this.cardText, this.cardImage, this.width, this.height, this.color, this.category, this.choiceCardCallback});
```

Next, when you are assigning a value to the variable in this case `color`:

```
color = Colors.red;
```

This would hopefully fix your error temporarily as flutter itself will find out the data type of `color`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update SDK version in pubspec.yaml (must be 2.6.0 or higher)

```yaml
environment:
   sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

2. Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean
3. File->Invalidate Cache/Restart

**OR**

If the above solution doesn't work, look for any unfinished code in your file or package and complete it. Or try to resolve other errors occurring in other parts of the file or the package. Analysis server can have errors if there are some unfinished code or other errors.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to build your app again. Stop running app and re-run your app. I faced this error but solved by re-running from start.

Answer (score 0):

I know, you are facing this error in dart latest version (V2.15.0). But don't be worried, please update your code.

Your error:

> Const variables must be initialized with a constant value. | Color isn't a type

**Why facing this Error?**
The meaning of this error you can not use constant value in the application runtime:

```
const Color pinkClr = Color(0xFFff4667);
```

Update Your code to:

```
final pinkClr = Color(0xFFff4667);
```

**Solution**:
Use the final keyword to use this constant value in the application runtime.